# Golang AppEngine memcache deadline exceeded

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a golang AppEngine application which runs a Monte Carlo- style simulation in parallel using the task queue, and makes heavy uses of memcache to store intermediate results. Everything works fine for small numbers of processes/tasks (< 100), but I'm finding that at large numbers (> 1000) I get a lot of failures to read or update intermediate data from memcache, with the error 'Canceled: Deadline exceeded'. This seems to happen 7-10 seconds after initialising a task. Particular offenders seem to be memcache.JSON.Get and memcache.IncrementExisting. Is it possible I'm overloading memcache somehow ?

Comment: Deadline Exceeded usually refers to request timeout from a handler. Are your handlers timing out by any chance? 10 mins for taskqueues and 60 secs for normal handlers.

Comment: It's definitely not a handler timeout; it's definitely a response to a  call to memcache and typically occurs after 7-10 secs

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 6519](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6519) might be relevant

> If you have appestats enabled, and the memcache logging exceeds 1mb,
>   it gets a "out of heap" error and then all subsequent memcache
>   sets/gets/admin calls fail.  Instance upload "fixes" the problem
>   temporarily.  I disabled appestats to fix the problem more
>   permanently.

Comment: Don't have appstats enabled

Answer (score 0):

Seems this was related to an underlying AppEngine infrastructure problem (now resolved)